# .NET Object Database of Specific Features

Tags: .net, database, linq, object

Anybody knows of a .NET object database that has the following:

1. embedded thread-safe
   transactional ACID operations
   (read/write/delete)
2. full LINQ support (and better PLINQ
   as well)
3. transparent lazy fetching of referenced
   objects (no need to inherent or implement anything)
4. indexing, advanced strings and collections/generics
   built-in support
5. clean/modern API actively developed

Comment: I think RavenDB is the one that fits the most of your bullet points. Doesn't have #3 though.

Comment: @driis: Thank you! RavenDB is document oriented and i think it is only useful with dynamic variables not typed objects, plus "select new {...}" operations are an overhead

Comment: You are right, Raven is document oriented. I do think it is very useful with typed objects though. You store a .NET object, it is nicely serialized, and you can get it back. It is not suited for serializing large complex object graphs, though. The only other object database I can think of that fits your needs would be db4o (again, don't know about #3 on your list). http://www.db4o.com/